# Append DataGridview with the servers output.. Currently getting overwritten

Tags: windows, forms, powershell, datagridview

Currently I am stuck with one project where as I am trying to show the output of `Get-WmiObject -Class OperatinSsytem` output from mulitple servers into a DataGridView.

Below is what has been done so far:

```
$MainForm_Load = {
    #TODO: Initialize Form Controls here
}

#region Control Helper Functions
function Load-DataGridView
{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
      This functions helps you load items into a DataGridView.

    .DESCRIPTION
      Use this function to dynamically load items into the DataGridView control.

    .PARAMETER  DataGridView
      The DataGridView control you want to add items to.

    .PARAMETER  Item
      The object or objects you wish to load into the DataGridView's items collection.

    .PARAMETER  DataMember
      Sets the name of the list or table in the data source for which the DataGridView is displaying data.

    .PARAMETER AutoSizeColumns
        Resizes DataGridView control's columns after loading the items.
    #>
    Param (
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView]$DataGridView,
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $Item,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$DataMember,
        [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode]$AutoSizeColumns = 'None'
    )
    $DataGridView.SuspendLayout()
    $DataGridView.DataMember = $DataMember

    if ($Item -is [System.Data.DataSet] -and $Item.Tables.Count -gt 0)
    {
        $DataGridView.DataSource = $Item.Tables[0]
    }
    elseif ($Item -is [System.ComponentModel.IListSource]`
    -or $Item -is [System.ComponentModel.IBindingList] -or $Item -is [System.ComponentModel.IBindingListView] )
    {
        $DataGridView.DataSource = $Item
    }
    else
    {
        $array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

        if ($Item -is [System.Collections.IList])
        {
            $array.AddRange($Item)
        }
        else
        {
            $array.Add($Item)
        }
        $DataGridView.DataSource = $array
    }

    if ($AutoSizeColumns -ne 'None')
    {
        $DataGridView.AutoResizeColumns($AutoSizeColumns)
    }

    $DataGridView.ResumeLayout()
}

function ConvertTo-DataTable
{
    <#
      .SYNOPSIS
        Converts objects into a DataTable.

      .DESCRIPTION
        Converts objects into a DataTable, which are used for DataBinding.

      .PARAMETER  InputObject
        The input to convert into a DataTable.

      .PARAMETER  Table
        The DataTable you wish to load the input into.

      .PARAMETER RetainColumns
        This switch tells the function to keep the DataTable's existing columns.

      .PARAMETER FilterWMIProperties
        This switch removes WMI properties that start with an underline.

      .EXAMPLE
        $DataTable = ConvertTo-DataTable -InputObject (Get-Process)
    #>
    [OutputType([System.Data.DataTable])]
    param(
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    $InputObject, 
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [System.Data.DataTable]$Table,
    [switch]$RetainColumns,
    [switch]$FilterWMIProperties)

    if($null -eq $Table)
    {
        $Table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    }

    if ($InputObject -is [System.Data.DataTable])
    {
        $Table = $InputObject
    }
    elseif ($InputObject -is [System.Data.DataSet] -and $InputObject.Tables.Count -gt 0)
    {
        $Table = $InputObject.Tables[0]
    }
    else
    {
        if (-not $RetainColumns -or $Table.Columns.Count -eq 0)
        {
            #Clear out the Table Contents
            $Table.Clear()

            if ($null -eq $InputObject) { return } #Empty Data

            $object = $null
            #find the first non null value
            foreach ($item in $InputObject)
            {
                if ($null -ne $item)
                {
                    $object = $item
                    break
                }
            }

            if ($null -eq $object) { return } #All null then empty

            #Get all the properties in order to create the columns
            foreach ($prop in $object.PSObject.Get_Properties())
            {
                if (-not $FilterWMIProperties -or -not $prop.Name.StartsWith('__')) #filter out WMI properties
                {
                    #Get the type from the Definition string
                    $type = $null

                    if ($null -ne $prop.Value)
                    {
                        try { $type = $prop.Value.GetType() }
                        catch { }
                    }

                    if ($null -ne $type) # -and [System.Type]::GetTypeCode($type) -ne 'Object')
                    {
                        [void]$table.Columns.Add($prop.Name, $type)
                    }
                    else #Type info not found
                    {
                        [void]$table.Columns.Add($prop.Name)
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($object -is [System.Data.DataRow])
            {
                foreach ($item in $InputObject)
                {
                    $Table.Rows.Add($item)
                }
                return @( ,$Table)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $Table.Rows.Clear()
        }

        foreach ($item in $InputObject)
        {
            $row = $table.NewRow()

            if ($item)
            {
                foreach ($prop in $item.PSObject.Get_Properties())
                {
                    if ($table.Columns.Contains($prop.Name))
                    {
                        $row.Item($prop.Name) = $prop.Value
                    }
                }
            }
            [void]$table.Rows.Add($row)
        }
    }

    return @(,$Table)   
}
#endregion

$buttonShow_Click = {
    $Servers = Get-Content $textbox1.Text
    foreach ($Server in $Servers)
    {
        $OS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Server
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Servers.count; $i++)
        {
            $table = ConvertTo-DataTable -InputObject $OS -FilterWMIProperties
            Load-DataGridView -DataGridView $datagridview1 -Item $table
            $datagridview1.DataSource = $table
        }
    }
}
```

Data is getting overwritten at the frist row and it's not appending. How to get the data of next server appended?

Comment: Please reduce that wall of code to the shortest script that still demonstrates the problem.

Comment: $buttonShow_Click = {
    $Servers = Get-Content $textbox1.Text
    foreach ($Server in $Servers)
    {
        $OS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Server
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Servers.count; $i++)
        {
            $table = ConvertTo-DataTable -InputObject $OS -FilterWMIProperties
            Load-DataGridView -DataGridView $datagridview1 -Item $table
            $datagridview1.DataSource = $table
        }
    }
}

Comment: Please edit your question. Code in comments is unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all these two lines does just about the same:

```
        Load-DataGridView -DataGridView $datagridview1 -Item $table
        $datagridview1.DataSource = $table
```

I changed your code a little so now it's should work.

```
$buttonShow_Click = {
    $Servers = Get-Content $textbox1.Text
    $set = @()
    foreach ($Server in $Servers)
    {
        $set += Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Server
    }
    $table = ConvertTo-DataTable -InputObject $set -FilterWMIProperties
    $datagridview1.DataSource = $table
}
```

Comment: what if I want to have different table headers than actual WMI property names ? for example, I am getting Win32_Operatingsystem property names as headers but i want to have ServerName instead of PSComputerName and instead of WindowsDirectory property my custom name like WinDir etc..

Comment: function Get-ServerInfo
{
 $Servers = Get-Content $textboxServers.Text
 $Set = @()
 foreach ($Server in $Servers)
 {$OS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Server
   
   $Prop = @{
    'ServerName' = $Server;
    'OS' = $OS.Caption;
    'InstallDir' = $OS.WindowsDirectory;
    'Version' = $OS.version;
    'ServicePack' = $OS.CSDVersion
   }
   New-Object PSObject -Property $Prop
   
   $table = ConvertTo-DataTable -InputObject $Set -FilterWMIProperties
   #Load-DataGridView -DataGridView $datagridview1 -Item $table
   $datagridview1.DataSource = $table

Comment: Just pipe properties you like after Get-WmiObject. Like so:  $set += Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Server | Select @{Name='NewName';Expression={$_.OldName}}

Comment: @AämërMöhammëd, $set += Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Server -Property * | Select -Property @{n='ServerName';e={$_.PSComputerName }},@{n='WinDir';e={$_.WindowsDirectory}},* -ExcludeProperty PSComputerName,WindowsDirectory

Comment: @AämërMöhammëd, you are welcome. You could mark my answer as an answer. That would might help someone else too!